# Trying to offline post to facebook users wall, need error checking, cannot find it in documentation

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to post to some users walls, i have the required permisions, but, some tokens are invalid, and some people only autherized the first step of oauth, and not the publish stream, so i am getting a bunch of errors, this is the code:

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => APP_ID,
    'secret' => APP_SECRET,
    'cookie' => false,
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);


$query = "SELECT * FROM `facebook-users` WHERE NOT token = '';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


     // success

     if (!empty($row['token'])) {
         $attachment = array(
         'access_token' => $row['token'],
         'message' => $message,
         'name' => $title,
         'link' => $link,
         'description' => $desc,
         'picture'=>$pic,
         'actions' => json_encode(array('name' => $action_name,'link' => $action_link))
         );

         $post_url = '/' . $row['uid'].'/feed';
         $status = $facebook->api($post_url, "post", $attachment);

         $count++;
}

echo $count;
die();
?>
```

So how do i error check on those basic errors, and continue even tho they occured?

Answer (score 0):

If the errors just show up when you do not have the required permissions to post to the user wall, why don't you just check it in the while loop?

Something like:

```
if(!($facebook->api($post_url, "post", $attachment))) continue;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /home/content/59/10667659/html/facebook/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1271

Comment: So if it's the API giving you the error directly you need to check the permissions before and then proceed if the user has given the right permission. As said by @Ene you need to check the permissions

Comment: The permissions might even not be sufficient for checking the permission, if the user can stop the OAuth flow at any time, leaving the app in an instable state?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a [long-live token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). You may check permissions at */id/permissions*, search for publish_stream. For testing, you can use the [Graph API Explorer console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: i have one, but, some users token is only valid to "read", while others have given exstended permissions

Answer (score 0):

You already got it:

```
Uncaught OAuthException: (#200)
```

Thus: put everything in try/catch blocks and catch those exceptions from the FB API properly. Its some hard work, since there is no doc on the **possible** errors like in the Google API, so you need to generate errors and look at the logs.